# Android React Native stuck at splashscreen

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-navigation

Sometimes, after being for a long time in background, my app doesn't load and get stuck at the splashscreen.

I was able to reproduce this in debug mode by:
- launching the app
- using debug js remotely
- kill the application
- launching the app

And in release mode by:
- launching the app
- go in Parameters
- dev options
- enable don't keep activities
- launching the app again

If I try to reproduce this bug with the release method while in debug mode i get the following error:

```
    Process: com.situaction, PID: 22308
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
        at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.close(RealWebSocket.java:164)
        at com.facebook.react.packagerconnection.ReconnectingWebSocket.closeWebSocketQuietly(ReconnectingWebSocket.java:110)
        at com.facebook.react.packagerconnection.ReconnectingWebSocket.closeQuietly(ReconnectingWebSocket.java:103)
        at com.facebook.react.packagerconnection.JSPackagerClient.close(JSPackagerClient.java:96)
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevServerHelper$2.doInBackground(DevServerHelper.java:158)
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevServerHelper$2.doInBackground(DevServerHelper.java:154)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

It seems to be linked to react-native-navigation and/or react-native-redux
so here is my dependencies:

```
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
"react-native": "0.43.3",
"react-native-navigation": "1.1.398",
"react-redux": "^5.0.5",
"redux": "^3.7.0",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.1",
"redux-observable": "^0.14.1",
"redux-persist": "^4.8.1",
"redux-persist-transform-filter": "0.0.13",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so if found out that it was a react-native-navigation problem.
I solved my problem by downgrading to the 1.1.250 version.

It seems to solve the problem since i can't reproduce it anymore and my app is working fine now.